# Convert Bigdecimal 123 to 123.00

Tags: java, bigdecimal

Below is the piece of code, I am trying to print `123 as 123.00` but it gives me `123`:

```
BigDecimal decimal = new BigDecimal(123);
decimal.doubleValue();
```

Can you please help me in printing `123 as 123.00`?

Comment: When i give it as 123.22 i want it to give the same output as entered

Comment: only on adding 123 it shud give me 123.00 in this case i don think rounding with scale will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(123);
value = value.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN)
```

You can refer [Javadocs for ROUND_HALF_EVEN](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#ROUND_HALF_EVEN) and [setScale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale(int,%20java.math.RoundingMode))

Comment: on adding 123.22 it will give me 123.00 in this case . I dont want that.                       Say if i enter 123 it shud give 123.00 but if i enter 123.456 it shud give 123.456 . But with the above solution it wil give 123.00 even in this case

Comment: @Chaitanya:- You mean you dont have a fixed length for the decimal format? or may be you can try to use `RoundingMode.CEILING`

Comment: By using this conditionally it works: 
Say
if(value.scale()==0){
 value = value.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN);
}
else{
just return as it is
}

Thanks Rahul :)

Answer (score 0):

If it's the number's format you are concerned about, do something like this:

```
BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(123.0023);
BigDecimal formatted = value.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN);
System.out.println(formatted.toPlainString());
```

Prints:

> 123.00

---

Credits to @Rahul Tripathi